# Possible to grant app permissions for specific users?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to build a service that looks at calendar information for users in our organization. This needs to be a background service and so needs to use app permissions rather than delegated permissions. However, I don't want to grant the application permission to look at everyone's calendars in the organization but only those participating in the program my application is facilitating.

It it possible to grant app permissions for specific users and not the whole organization? In this particular case, it would be permission to read basic calendar information for about 5 individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you (your admin tenant) can create an application access policy to limit app access to specific mailboxes.

Check doc for more details:

[Limiting application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?view=graph-rest-1.0)